# Java Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

Working on a project for school and I'm getting a error when I try to enter the number of students for the array. The error is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
>   at Project1.enterStudents(Project1.java23)
>   at Project1.mainMenu(Project1.java59)
>   at Project1.enterStudents(Project1.java7)

The code I have written it below as always any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project1{
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Project1 project1 = new Project1();
project1.mainMenu();


}//main

int numOfStudents;
Student[] students = new Student[numOfStudents];

public void enterStudents(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of students");
    numOfStudents = input.nextInt();
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= numOfStudents - 1; i++){
        i--;
        System.out.println("Enter student's ID: ");
        students[i].getId();
        System.out.println("Enter student's first name: ");
        students[i].getFirst();
        System.out.println("Enter student's last name: ");
        students[i].getLast();
        System.out.println("Enter student's class: ");
        students[i].getStuClass();
    }


}

public void retrieveStuId(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter student id");


}

public void Exit(){
    System.exit(0);
}

public void mainMenu(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1 - Enter student info");
    System.out.println("2 - Retrieve student by ID");
    System.out.println("3 - Retrieve student by last name");
    System.out.println("4 - Update student");
    System.out.println("5 - Exit");
    int menuSelect = input.nextInt();

    if (menuSelect != 1 && menuSelect != 2 && menuSelect != 3 && menuSelect != 4 && menuSelect != 5)
        System.out.println("That is not a option");
    else
        switch (menuSelect){
            case 1: enterStudents();

            case 2: System.out.print("case 2");

            case 3: System.out.print("case 3");

            case 4: System.out.print("case 4");

            case 5: Exit();

        }
}

}//project1

class Student{
private int studentID;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String stuClass;

public Student(){
}

public Student(int id, String first, String last, String c ){
    studentID = id;
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    stuClass = c;
}

public void setID (int id){
    studentID = id;
}

public void  setStuClass (String c){
    stuClass = c;
}

public void setFirst(String first){
    firstName = first;
}

public void setLast(String last){
    lastName = last;
}

public String getFirst(){
    return firstName;
}

public String getLast(){
    return lastName;
}

public int getId(){
    return studentID;
}

public String getStuClass(){
    return stuClass;
} 

public String toString(){
    return "Student ID: " + studentID + " ---- " + "Student Name: " + firstName + "" + lastName + " ---- " + "Class:" + stuClass;
}


}
```

Comment: Please identify which is line 23

Comment: @TedHopp I can easily guess that it's `students[i].getId();`. Loop starts with index `0`, then gets decremented to `-1`, arrays do not have such index.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at this bit of code:

```
for(i = 0; i <= numOfStudents - 1; i++){
    i--;
    System.out.println("Enter student's ID: ");
    students[i].getId();
```

Now work out what the value of `i` is going to be on each line...

Why do you have the `i--;` line at all?

Note that this *only* addresses the first `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` issue - once that's fixed, you'll end up with another `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you're initializing the array *before* asking for `numOfStudents`.

Once *that's* addressed, you'll get a `NullPointerException` because you're trying to call methods via null references - you never actually *create* a new `Student` instance.

To be honest, this program is quite a long way from working - I'm not sure that Stack Overflow is going to provide the most effective teaching environment in this particular case. I would suggest you talk to your teacher and ask for some 1-on-1 tutoring.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = 0; i <= numOfStudents - 1; i++){
// REMOVE THIS        i--;
// i is = -1 here but Arrays start by 0
    System.out.println("Enter student's ID: ");
    students[i].getId();
    System.out.println("Enter student's first name: ");
    students[i].getFirst();
    System.out.println("Enter student's last name: ");
    students[i].getLast();
    System.out.println("Enter student's class: ");
    students[i].getStuClass();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `i--;` at the top of your loop body is a likely culprit. In fact, if it wasn't causing this problem, I think it'd make your loop run forever. Why is that even there?

Also, I see another problem. When the array `students` is initialized, `numOfStudents` has not yet been assigned a value. Since it's an instance variable, it defaults to 0, which means `students` won't actually hold any Students.

Answer (score 1):

Why this?

```
for(i = 0; i <= numOfStudents - 1; i++){
        i--; //<--THIS
```

The problem is probably there. You are tryng to access to an array with a negative index number.

Answer (score 1):

`int numOfStudents` is initialized to nothing. 
so attempting to edit your students array will not work.

How to fix it:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of students"); 
int numOfStudents = input.nextInt(); //this initializes to something.
Student[] students = new Student[numOfStudents];
```

then continue with your loop gathering the data.

Of course, you will want to remove the `i--` as pointed out by others.

Answer (score 0):

It's the i-- in your loop in enterStudents. This causes the index to go from 0 to -1 which is invalid. What exactly is this i-- supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like others here have already pointed out the answer, but here's how to fish...

The fact that it's an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` tells you that it's happening while you're accessing an array, and it's even kind enough to tell you the index you've used that's out of bounds (in this case, -1, which is always out of bounds -- array indexes must be >= 0).

`enterStudents` only uses one array, and its index always comes from one variable. So, mentally step through your code and follow the values of that variable `i` to see if/how it can ever be -1.

Btw, `for(i = 0; i <= numOfStudents - 1; i++)` will work, but `for(i = 0; i < numOfStudents; i++)` is a bit more idiomatic.